# Invalid SSL certificate for Wikimedia, only on my PC and only on LAN; resolves correctly on Wi-Fi

Tags: ssl, certificate, https

Since yesterday I'm having trouble with anything related to the https://upload.wikimedia.org/ URLs, they all give an `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error.

I tried some troubleshooting and I noticed that SSL Checker detects no errors ( https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://upload.wikimedia.org/ ) and even trying visiting the URLs with a proxy website like https://www.proxysite.com/ works.

I noticed that the certificate I get on my side looks suspicious to say the least. What is `sinkhole.duskrise.com`?

[image]

This happens with every browser and even within the Windows 11 Sandbox Mode. Note that on Wi-Fi everything works, the problem seems to appear only when connected via LAN. I am using a Home&Life HUB, provided by my ISP (WindTre).

Could this be malware related? Please note that this is the only site I'm having trouble with, Wikipedia works fine, except all the images not showing being hosted on `wikimedia.org`.

Comment: I get for this URL redirected immediately to [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) and the certificate belongs to "wikipedia.org". You may use the Developer Tools of the browser to trace the internet request and the answer, to see what's happening. Try also to empty the browser's cache.

Comment: Have you checked your local certificates to see if something matching this is installed? Have you checked for malware?

Comment: @harrymc try this direct link to an image https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Google_Calendar_icon_%282020%29.svg/768px-Google_Calendar_icon_%282020%29.svg.png

Comment: @music2myear I tried with a few different browsers but they all have the same problem. Also tried what this post ( https://www.shareus.com/windows/how-to-clear-ssl-state-in-browsers-on-windows-10.html ) suggested, with no success

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Computing

Comment: The image URL is not redirected, but the certificate still belongs to "wikipedia.org" and is verified by DigiCert. It dates from October 18, 2023, which is later than yours.

Comment: @Gantendo thanks for the link, I didn't know where to ask, I also posted there now

Comment: I just tried running a malware scan and nothing came out

Comment: @bimbo1989 Try malwarebytes free if you haven't already (not sure what you used to scan for malware)

Comment: @Gantendo just tried Malwarebytes, found nothing. Not malware related maybe, but if not malware, what?

Comment: I've got news: only happens when connected via LAN and not on Wi-Fi. Same computer. Router related?

Comment: You (or your router) are running a security product by Duskrise. What antivirus product are you running? A sinkhole may be something similar to a honeypot or to a /null output for network traffic. Duskrise is a threat detection and network security organization. So, look at your computer's security setup, and at the same on your router. It is likely that one of those locations has some Duskrise product.

Comment: You could ask the IT department of your company or contact Duskrise here https://get.duskrise.com/contact

Comment: Your IT Administrator has configured your network to purposefully route traffic through [Google Trust Services](https://pki.goog/) As other have suggested, your system is configured to use Duskrise, which obviously utilize Google Trust Services. Everything you tried is using the same network connection, even Windows Sandbox, so look towards your the modem connected to your service provider, any routers that you have enable security features on, even security products installed on the system. **The behavior absolutely is NOT malware.** because Duskrise and GTS is a legitimate service

Comment: What kind of router are you using? Perhaps that’s something to add to the question.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Home&Life HUB, provided by my ISP (WindTre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own, I have no clue about how it worked, I just found out by tinkering around.
[image]

I had this set up with a manual IP (please note it was ALWAYS this way, I didn't change anything). Switched to DHCP and everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Duskrise](https://www.duskrise.com/) is a security software company. You are getting redirected to https://sinkhole.duskrise.com/ because the site is blocked for you:

[image]

This is probably your local IT security, but Wikimedia may have banned you/your IP, or something tertiary like Google workspaces may be blocking it.

Comment: They will ban you from editing if you are naughty, but not from looking at [cute cat pictures](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?search=cat&title=Special%3AMediaSearch&fulltext=Search) on the website

Comment: There's no IT security department there, it's my computer :)

Comment: Also note that on wi-fi everything works, the problem seems to appear only when connected via LAN

Comment: Anyway I'll try and contact my ISP tomorrow

Comment: This is clearly client ISP level since if it were Wikimedia, they would block you at their servers (final destination) and not via a 3rd party.

Comment: There is still one thing I don't get: why does this happen only on LAN and not on wifi? Remember this is a home network, not a corporate one

Comment: @Giacomo1968 DuskRise/C25 does cloud security stuff too, and could be sinkholing at the CDN level like cloudflare if they think you're ddosing or being malicious (though probably not the case here)

Comment: @bimbo1989 Does your home router have some sort of web security? It's behaving kind of like a DNS redirection (try and flush your DNS cache) or a permanent http 301 redirect (clear your browser cache). AT&T used to do this kind of thing with their internal DNS service. You can bypass it by using a different provider like https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setup/windows/

Comment: @Cpt.Whale already tried flushing everything I could flush, in the router settings I found nothing weird